# how to determine the exact value of the capacitor for a particular package using the datasheet

Tags: capacitor, datasheet, capacitance

how to determine the exact value of the capacitor for a particular package ?
In normal case datasheet of the capacitor generally gives capacitor values withing wide ranges like 120 pF to 300 nF for a particular package.
Take this datasheet as a example http://www.vishay.com/docs/45199/vjcommercialseries.pdf in this case capacitance value for the package 1206 is varying from 1.0 pF to 10 nF which is four orders of magnitude. So which value am i supposed to use in calculation ?
Is there any curve followed by these caps for their value change dependent on temperature or volatge?
How to find the capacitor value for that package for normal operating condition?

Comment: A specific capacitor will have a specific capacitance, it's just that the case sizes are standardised so you can get many different values in the same package. The values are usually printed on the case (with the annoyingly notable exception of SMD capacitors)

Comment: What exactly are you asking?  Are you asking how to select capacitor values for a specific circuit?  Or are you asking how to determine the capacitance value of some particular part?  Please clarify your question so that people can understand what you are asking.

Comment: You can always measure it.  Most capacitors don't have very tight tolerances.

Answer (score 1):

with the help of capacitance colour coding like the colour coding of resistance here i am giving the colour coding chart for capacitance for all type of capacitances[image: capacity colour coding]

by using this we can easily found the capacitances

Comment: The packages and coding shown on that chart are truly ancient.  They were obsolete when I started working in electronics ~1960.  Also, I don't think this really addresses the OP's question (although I'm not quite sure what his question is.).

Comment: I didn't even know there were, once upon a time, color coding for capacitors. Anyway, yes, nobody could appropriately answer the OP's question as it is stated currently.

Comment: @dim Oh, yes! I've some quality polymer caps in my junk box that I scrapped from old equipment 20-something years ago. They are color coded that way.

Comment: @LorenzoDonati And - well, it's off-topic, but it won't make things much worse here - can you enlighten me on the µµfd mentions on that chart? what does it mean "micro-micro" Farads ? pico Farads ?

Comment: @dim Exactly! Before the International System was adopted widely, the "pico" prefix wasn't used much, so they used a double prefix (which is nowadays banned by the SI rules on unit prefixes).

Comment: @dim And they also used mF or MFD to actually mean "microfarad", since the greek letter "mu" wasn't easy to print on components (some manufacturers lacked it in the fonts of the printing machines used at the time!)

Comment: @LorenzoDonati Wow. Confusing, to say the least. Too bad the date isn't mentioned on the chart. Well, anyway, I learnt some things thanks to this answer. Upvote! (even if it doesn't make much sense).

Comment: @dim I cannot say for other countries, but in Italy those markings were almost obsolete at least since late '70s.